# how to delete a repeat value between tow array in c#

Tags: c#

**hi please help me**

```
string [] s = new string []{1 , 2 , 3 };
string [] e = new string [] {1 , 2 ,4};
```

the output what I want are :
1 2 3 4

Comment: Combine the arrays into a list, then use a method of list to get a list of distinct strings.

Comment: Load them into a hashset

Comment: This question has many answers on Google.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a `string[]`, however your values are `int`. You must either use `string` values or change the type of your `array` to `int`.

`Union` of `IEnumerable` is the function you're looking for and it does everything for you.

```
int [] s = new int [] {1, 2, 3}; 
int [] e = new int [] {1, 2, 4};

int[] union = s.Union(e).ToArray();
```